# Destructuring a list containing two items to use it as arguments to a binary function

Tags: list-manipulation, scripting, functional-style

I'm experimenting with the [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) function. I suspect there is a way to use that function to obtain both the mean and difference of two values. But this doesn't work:

```
 Through[{Mean, Subtract}[1175., 247.]]
```

It reports the error:

> Mean::argx: Mean called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.

The corollary raises a similar error:

```
 Through[{Mean, Subtract}[{1175., 247.}]]
```

> Subtract::argr: Subtract called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.

I think the problem is caused by the [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) function taking only one argument as a list of values, whereas [`Subtract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subtract.html) takes its arguments as two separate values. It reminds me of destructuring as found in other languages, hence the title. Feel free to edit that for something more descriptive.

Is there a way to do what I try? Since I'm learning the Wolfram Language, I would prefer a solution working in the general case rather that a solution specific to the Mean and Subtract functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you ask

```
Through[{Mean@*List, Subtract}[1175., 247.]]
(* {711., 928.}*)
```

This works by using `Composition` (in its operator form) to apply `List` and then `Mean` to the inputs.

You could also "Lift" (is that the correct functional programming term?) `Subtract` to operate on lists (as suggested by @LukasLang)

```
Through[{Mean, Apply[Subtract]}[{1175., 247.}]]
(* {711., 928.}*)
```

Comment: I knew there was some `@...` notation that would be involved. Thank @mikado. Could you ellaborate a little on the way it works?

Comment: It might be worth to add `Through[{Mean, Apply@Subtract}[1175., 247.]]` as the "inverse" approach (where a list is supplied and converted to a sequence of arguments)

Comment: @Lukas, Thank you! I took the liberty of editing the Mikado's answer to quote your comment (I also fixed a small typo in the code where you wrote `[1175., 247.]` for `[{1175., 247.}]`. Feel free to revert that edit if you desagree.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to force Mean to aggregate the two arguments into a list,

```
Through[{Mean[{##}] &, Subtract}[1175., 247.]]
```

Please notice the double `##`. With only one `#` the mean will be applied only on the first argument.

Or you can modify the call to Subtract to force it to break the list into separate arguments:

```
Through[{Mean, Subtract[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &}[{1175., 247.}]]
```

Comment: I saw something like that already. It wraps `Mean` in a lambda function. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I know what a lambda function is... the first one operates by placing the argument 1175., 247 where the # is, so that the two numbers are placed into a list (as required by Mean). The second works the opposite, by separating the list argument into its two components (as required by Subtract).

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Mathematica's equivalent of a lambda function is referred to as a "Pure" function.  See the help on `Function` for an explanation.

Comment: I think the first one should be `Mean[{##}]&` - otherwise, you will keep only the first argument

Comment: You're right @Lukas. I' editing Bill's answer with that. I add en extra explntion of the problem, since one-character edits are not allowed. Feel free to edit that if I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0}

```
Comap[{Mean, Apply @ Subtract}] @ {1175., 247.}
```

{711., 928.}

Using `ComapApply` (also new in 14.0}

```
ComapApply[{Mean @* List, Subtract}] @ {1175., 247.}
```

{711., 928.}

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Thread`:

```
#1@{##2} & @@@ Thread[{{Mean, Apply@Subtract}, Splice@{1175., 247.}}]

(*{711., 928.}*)
```